# TYPO3 9: Disabled page shows up in navigation after enabling site configuration

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

After a TYPO3 update from version 8.7 to 9.5 the website shows disabled pages in the navigation or sitemap module of `ext:fluid_styled_content` as soon as I add a site configuration. The config.yaml just holds this information:

```
base: /
baseVariants: {  }
errorHandling: {  }
languages:
  -
    title: Deutsch
    enabled: true
    base: /
    typo3Language: de
    locale: de_DE.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: de
    navigationTitle: ''
    hreflang: ''
    direction: ''
    flag: global
    languageId: '0'
rootPageId: 1
routes: {  }
```

Just to make sure, that it is not related to my TypoScript configuration, I installed `ext:bootstrap_package` and disabled my "template" extension. But this did not help, the disabled pages showed up as well.

After removing the `rootPageId: 1` from the sites configuration, the disabled pages are not shown in the navigation.

Does anybody knows, what goes wrong or even how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of debugging, I realized, that the extension `frontent_editing` caused this error. I had version 1.7.0 running and it was fixed in version 1.8.2. See [bug report](https://github.com/FriendsOfTYPO3/frontend_editing/issues/380).

So after upgrading to current version 1.8.3 disabled pages are hidden in the navigation and sitemap menus again.

Answer (score 0):

when you are talking about "hidden" you can try:

```
tt_content.menu_sitemap.dataProcessing.10.includeNotInMenu = 0
```

Comment: No, unfortunaltely I am really talking about disabled pages.

Comment: And you're getting the pages only in menus? Can you access them (without "Preview"-Badge)? Are you logged-in in the Backend?

Comment: @JulianHofmann Yes, I am getting the pages only in the menus and no, I am not logged in and I can't access them. As soon, as I click the page in the menu, I get an error 404, which is correct.

Comment: Sorry, @chris, can't reproduce this behavior. Have you already tested this in a second TYPO3 instance?

Comment: @JulianHofmann Do you mean on another server? No, I have not tested on another server yet. Or do you mean a clean TYPO3 installation? I have indeed installed a blank TYPO3 9.5 page with the bootstrap package and I can't reproduce this behaviour there. But the website I am working on is an update from TYPO3 8 to 9. Do you have any hints, where to start debugging? I have output some debug messages in the `MenuProcessor` but don't get other information with and without configured the site.

Comment: @JulianHofmann Thanks for pushing me into the right direction. As I supposed the error in my setup and didn't think of disable other 3rd party extensions. But now I did and voila, `ext:frontend_editing`caused this error. See my answer.